# Spring Core 5 + Postgresql 10.4 + C3p0 issue when setting CLOB value (not using Hibernate)

Tags: spring, postgresql, c3p0, clob

I've upgraded my application to use Spring Core version 5.0.8 (previously it was using version 4.3.6).
My app uses Postgresql 10.4 with JDBC driver version 42.2.5 and C3p0 version 0.9.5.2.

After the Spring Core upgrade, the application started throwing the following exception when trying to set the value of a CLOB column:

```
Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setClob(int, Reader, long) is not yet implemented.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setClob(int, Reader, long) is not yet implemented
```

I saw that the method `setValue` of spring class `org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils` changed on latest versions and now it is not catching the exception `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` and using a fallback method anymore, as it did on previous versions.

I've seen several answers related to workarounds when using JPA/Hibernate but it is not my case, the application does not use Hibernate at all.

What could I do to solve this issue? Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Mariana